# How to use block handler for getting return value when timer running in objective-c (IOS)

Tags: ios, timer, block

I have a timer that run on 10 minutes. I want to get time at the 5th minute for some actions before end time (the 10th minute). May be not use block handler if you have another better solution.

Comment: Can you post your code that you've tried?

Comment: @ShawnMehan: I haven't tried to code. I want to ask the solution first. With timer, i use scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval.

Comment: And there's part of your problem. go read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score -1):

```
NSTimeInterval duration = 10 * 600;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(duration * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self func];
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use "performSelector" to do whatever you want at the 5th minute.